# How do I shutdown a background worker thread without calling application::doevents?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, backgroundworker, shutdown, resource-cleanup

Suppose I have a GUI application which has a background thread which runs for the lifetime of the application. When I close the application I want to close off any of these background threads cleanly. In reality I often have a few threads running to perform data collection and processing activities without hanging up the GUI.

The example below demonstrates the problem; namely that if you cancel the background worker, it tries to call the worker complete method on the main thread. Without a call to `Application::DoEvents()` the code will just hang indefinitely, but I've run into issues with calling `DoEvents` before and my gut tells me it's bad practice.

So the question is; When my application exits, what's the right way to cleanly shutdown the background worker thread?

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
///
/// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
///          resources associated with this form.
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private: System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker^  backgroundWorker1;

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 
        // backgroundWorker1
        // 
        this->backgroundWorker1 = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker());
        this->backgroundWorker1->DoWork += gcnew System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        this->backgroundWorker1->ProgressChanged += gcnew System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if( backgroundWorker1 != nullptr )
        {
            backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();
        }

        while( backgroundWorker1->IsBusy == true )
        {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Waiting for background worker to exit..");
            System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
            // Application::DoEvents(); <-- Don't want to do this but what are the alternatives?
        }

        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Form1 destructor complete!");
    }

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
             while( backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending == false )
             {
                 System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Working..");
                 System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
             }
         }

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e) {
         }

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e)
         {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Exiting..");
            System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);

         }

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(443, 343);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion

};
```

Comment: Found a possible solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/csharpgeneral/thread/14679d00-3d46-4de4-be87-e66c196f0638

Comment: And [a possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732737/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-correctly) with at least [one answer advocating the use of `DoEvents`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625188/15369)...

Comment: [Some interesting background information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx) on DoEvents...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When BackgroundWorker fires the RunWorkerCompleted event, it does so on the main GUI thread, which is the one that the destructor is running on. When you call DoEvents, it gives the framework a chance to run other tasks that are waiting to run on that thread, including the RunWorkerCompleted event.

I added `Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId` to your debug messages (and uncommented `Application::DoEvents()`), and here's what I got:

```
Starting background worker from thread 1
Working on thread 3..
Working on thread 3..
Waiting on thread 1 for background worker to exit..
Exiting on thread 1..
Form1 destructor complete!
```

So, if you don't want to use Application::DoEvents(), I'd use a different mechanism to tell the UI thread that the worker has exited. A ManualResetEvent will do the trick nicely here.

```
private:
    ManualResetEvent^ mre;

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this->backgroundWorker1 = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker());
        this->backgroundWorker1->DoWork += gcnew System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        // Don't use this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerCompleted
        this->backgroundWorker1->ProgressChanged += gcnew System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        this->mre = gcnew ManualResetEvent(false);

        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Starting background worker from thread {0}", Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId);
        backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
    }

protected:
    ~Form1()
    {
        if( backgroundWorker1 != nullptr )
        {
            backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();
        }

        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Waiting on thread {0} for background worker to exit..", Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId);
        this->mre->WaitOne();

        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Form1 destructor complete!");
    }

private:
    System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e)
        {
            try
            {
                while( backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending == false )
                {
                    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Working on thread {0}..", Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId);
                    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this->mre->Set();
            }
        }
```

Now, all that said, you may want to consider using a regular Thread here, rather than a BackgroundWorker. By firing the 'completed' and 'progress' events onto the UI thread, I think it's more geared toward tasks that are too long to do directly on the UI thread, but where the result will be visible in the UI a few seconds later. (Firing the events on the UI thread makes it easy to update UI controls with the result of the operation.) For what you've shown here, something that's running the entire time that the form is open, you're not getting a big benefit from BackgroundWorker, so you could just create a thread and do it yourself.