# Backgroundworker doesn't stop

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, backgroundworker

DoWork is this:

```
        DoLengthyWork();

        //this is never executed
        if(bgWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Up to here? ...");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

I trigger the cancelation in with bgWorker.CancelAsync();

If **bgWorker.CancellationPending** cannot be reached because it's blocked by DoLengthyWork HOW can I stop the BackGround Worker ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732737/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-correctly

Comment: you need to get that `bgWorker.CancelAsync()` trigger inside your `DoLengthyWork()` so you can create a safe method to cancel the pending job. .NET does not cancel the job for you, it only set's to be canceled through `CancellationPending` property.

Comment: @Yuval, All that thread does is explain why my problem can't be solved. Thanks anyway ! ;)

Comment: It explains what has to be done.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the execution of your `DoWork` function won't reach `CancellationPending` condition ever. In fact, As balexandre said, you should know that organize `DoLengthyWork` scenario to check `CancellationPending` condition periodically inside it.

Comment: If you read my question completelly you would have noticed that I know what my problem is!