# Cancel button wait for BackgroundWorker to finish (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, backgroundworker

I'm working with C# ASP.NET Web Application. There is a problem that is difficult to track in the code. 
Let's say I have two buttons: *Upload* (which uploads some data from DataTable to Database) and *Cancel* (which cancels the uploading process). The problem is that uploading process runs in the BackgroundWorker. When user clicks *Upload* and uploading starts and then he clicks *Cancel* the *Cancel_Button_Click* event does not fire until BackgroundWorker is uploading data.

I have code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

protected void Upload_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); }

protected void Cancel_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); }

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{ };
```

So what really happens is when you click *Upload* and *Cancel* is method *private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged* runs many times (one time for every row of data, I suppose) and ONLY THEN method *Cancel_Button_Click* runs.

What to do, if I want to stop data uploading right after *Cancel* button is clicked?

Thaaaanks! :)

P.S. I tried searching on the net but I don't even know how to describe my problem in one sentence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop BackgroundWorker correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732737/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-correctly)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. :) Pretty different problems. :(