# is it possible to BackgroundWorker will wait to another?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

```
foreach (string file in listToConvert)
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        newFile = sendFilesToConvert(file);
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(newFile);
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

each file from the list will convert to another and i want that each BackgroundWorker will wait untill it's finish to convert and only then the next BackgroundWorker  will start
how can i do it ?

Comment: Why don't you want to convert all the files in one BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Why would you want to use background workers then? Either way you can simply start your new background workers in the completed event of each previous one.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using. If you are using 4.0, you could use a single background worker and a concurrent queue.

Comment: @oxilumin Oh, you read past the question and actually looked at the code! :) yeah, that would make a lot more sense.

Comment: can you show me how please ? i am using .Net 3.5

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333058/how-to-wait-correctly-until-backgroundworker-completes#answer-1333948

Comment: ok - deleted my answer and changed your tags ...

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a Bgw in each run of the loop. That's not a good idea anyway.

Just run the `foreach()` inside one single Bgw.

You can use the progress event to Add the results to the listbox or collect them in a list and Add them all at once when you're finished.

Comment: This is better than the ConcurrentQueue idea!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TPL for this:

```
   Task<List<newFile>> task1 = Task<List<newFile>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      List<newFile> newFiles = new List<newFile>();
     foreach(string file in fileList)
     {
        newFiles.Add(SendFilesToConvert(file));
     };

     return newFilesList;
   });


   foreach(newFile nFile in task1.Result)
   {
     listBoxFiles.Items.Add(nFile);
   };
```

Comment: i am using .Net 3.5 which not include Task

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to update a UI element (`listBoxFiles`) in your scenario. So you can use the following code:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
var filesList = // clone your listToConvert if it's not a local variable or other threads can access it

backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s3, e3) =>
               {
                   foreach (string file in filesList)
                   {
                       var newFile = sendFilesToConvert(file);
                       context.Post(x => listBoxFiles.Items.Add(newFile), null);

                       // Report progress
                   }
               };

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

this code posts a message (asynchronously) to your UI thread every time it needs to update your UI control, then UI thread dispatches it message and executes the code (`ListBox.Items.Add(...)`) in proper context.