# Wait til background worker finishes before calling method

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker that copies some files.  After it finishes copying the files, I want to launch an application. The problem I am running into is that while the files are copying, it calls the code to launch the application, so it runs into a file in use error. Is there a check I can do to ensure that a certain method is only called when the background worker has completed?

```
private void LaunchApplication(string targetPath, string targetExecutable)
    {
            CopyFiles();

            Process.Start(Path.Combine(targetPath, targetExecutable));
    }
```

CopyFiles is called within the DoWork method of the BackGroundWorker.  I want this to completely finsih before Process.Start... is called.  Now I have several executables tied to several buttons, so I can't put the Process.Start... in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: Are you making use of the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event?

Comment: You could check that the files have copied before running the application.

Comment: @DGibbs - Yes, but the problem there is that I have several applications that can be launched and I can't tell which one it is until the user clicks one of the launch buttons.

Comment: @SamLeach - How can I determine this?

Comment: @Xaisoft I'm not sure I understand... couldn't you just prevent the buttons from doing anything if the worker isn't complete?

Comment: @DGibbs - I'll put a snippet of code which might help understand the problem

Comment: @SamLeach - Would one option might be to have a private variable that is set to true after the file copy is done and then only call Process.Start... if that is true?

Comment: Use FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter Property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx

Comment: Is the code that calls `CopyFiles()` run in the same thread as the BG worker? I'm still not seeing a reason why you can't just set a flag to true when the run worker completed event is fired, then use this in `LaunchApplication`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice

Comment: I'll join in here - I think we need to see the bigger picture here.  How do the button presses related to the copy files.  You state  that "After it finishes copying the files, I want to launch an application", but then you say "I have several executables tied to several buttons, so I can't put the Process.Start... in the RunWorkerCompleted event".  This is a bit confusing in itself!  Could you expand your example?!

Comment: `if (!bgw.IsBusy) { Process.Start(...); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you put `CopyFiles()` in a background thread the next line of code will be executed, so in your case, I would **not** use a background worker.  Instead I would block until the copy files completes and then start the application.  Put up some sort of window telling your uses to wait a bit.

If you need to wait and still use a background worker, then `CopyFiles()` should be in the `DoWork` handler and `Process.Start` should be `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

MSDN on RunWorkerCompleted

[RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx)

Stack Overflow Example on Completed:

[Run Worker Completed Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333058/how-to-wait-correctly-until-backgroundworker-completes)

Also, you can create a global mutex to ensure only one launch is happening at a time so if you get multiple launches only one will be processed.

[Stack Overflow Global Mutex Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567)

Comment: The problem I have with putting Process.Start in RunWOrkerCompleted is that there are about 6 buttons that launch different applications and I have no idea which one the user clicked.

Comment: @Xaisoft - You could add click handlers for each button, or one handler for all of them.  The handler will have a 'object sender' argument that is passed.  Cast it to a Button and you could find the name of the button if you are using the generic handler approach.

Comment: So do you copy the files when the button is pressed or just open the exe? if you're copying the files then you could pass the executable path as an argument to the background worker. If you are just opening the exe on button click then just check if the background worker is busy with `bgw.IsBusy`