# Backgroundworker cancel the worker

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I'm facing some troubles when trying to cancel the Backgroundworker.
I've read dozens os similiar topics such as [How to stop BackgroundWorker correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732737/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-correctly), [How to wait correctly until BackgroundWorker completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333058/how-to-wait-correctly-until-backgroundworker-completes) but I'm not reaching anywhere.

What's happening is that I have a C# application that uses a PHP WebService to send info to a MySQL database. If the user, for some reason, clicks (in the form) on the "back" or "stop" button, this is the code that is fired:

```
BgWorkDocuments.CancelAsync();
BgWorkArticles.CancelAsync();
```

I do understand that the request is `Asynchronous`, therefore the cancelation might take 1 or 2 seconds, but it should stop..and that doesn't happen at all. Even after clicked "back" (the current form is closed and a new one is opened) the backgroundworker continues to work, because I keep seeing data being inserted into MySQL.

```
foreach (string[] conn in lines)
 {

    string connectionString = conn[0];

    FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(connectionString);
    fbConn.Open();

    getDocuments(fbConn);

    // Checks if one of the backgrounds is currently busy
    // If it is, then keep pushing the events until stop.
    // Only after everything is completed is when it's allowed to close the connection.
    // 
    // OBS: Might the problem be here?
    while (BgWorkDocuments.IsBusy == true || BgWorkArticles.IsBusy == true)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    fbConn.Close();
}
```

The above code is needed because I might have multiple databases, that's why I have the loop.

```
private void getDocuments(FbConnection fbConn)
{
    BgWorkDocuments.RunWorkerAsync();

    BgWorkDocuments.DoWork += (object _sender, DoWorkEventArgs args) =>
    {

        DataTable dt = getNewDocuments(fbConn);

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            // Checks if the user has stopped the background worker
            if (BgWorkDocuments.CancellationPending == false)
            {
                // Continue doing what has to do..
                sendDocumentsToMySQL((int)dt.Rows[i]["ID"]);
            }
        }

        // After the previous loop is completed, 
        // start the new backgroundworker

        getArticles(fbConn);

    };
}

private void getArticles(FbConnection fbConn)
{
    BgWorkArticles.RunWorkerAsync();

    BgWorkArticles.DoWork += (object _sender, DoWorkEventArgs args) =>
    {

        DataTable dt = getNewArticles(fbConn);

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            // Checks if the user has stopped the background worker
            if (BgWorkArticles.CancellationPending == false)
            {
                // Continue doing what has to do..
                sendArticlesToMySQL((int)dt.Rows[i]["ID"]);
            }
        }

    }; 
}
```

Comment: You're launching into the second thread regardless of what happens during the first.  So cancelling during `getDocuments()` will not prevent `getArticles()` from firing.  Do you need a `return` in that `getDocument()` call?

Comment: And lose the `DoEvents()` call...it's a bad idea.  Find another way to refresh if that's what you're after.

Comment: I agree with you, and I've changed the code that verifies if canceled to this: http://pastebin.com/3uEfNZqa, the same code (changing only the backgroundworker name) was applied to the getArticles() as well..but the problem persists.

Comment: See this pattern.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx  You need to pass the sender and cancel the sender

Comment: You're starting the workers before the dowork events are attached, how does this even works?

Comment: The result I'm trying to achieve is to `getDocuments()` firstly and after that `getArticles()` and ONLY when `getArticles()` is done is when the first loop can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments expressing surprise that the code even works, due to the apparent ordering problem of the call to `RunWorkerAsync()` vs when you actually subscribe to the `DoWork` event. Additionally, your use of `DoEvents()` is unwarranted and should be removed (as is the case with *any* use of `DoEvents()`).

I also note that your workers don't actually *exit* when you try to cancel them. You just skip the processing, but continue to loop on the rows. Without seeing the rest of the code, it's impossible to know what's going on, but it's *possible* that after you cancel, the `CancellationPending` property gets reset to `false`, allowing the loops to start doing things again.

The lack of a complete code example is a real impediment to understanding the full detail of what's going on.

That said, IMHO this does not seem to be a case where you actually need `BackgroundWorker` at all, not with the new `async`/`await` feature in C#. Given that network I/O is involved, my guess is that each call to `sendDocumentsToMySQL()` and `sendArticlesToMySQL()` can be executed individually in the thread pool without too much overhead (or may even be able to be written as async I/O methods…again, lacking detail as to their specific implementation prevents any specific advise in that respect). Given that, your code could probably be rewritten so that it looks more like this:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource;

private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_cancelSource != null)
    {
        _cancelSource.Cancel();
    }
}

private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource)
    {
        _cancelSource = cancelSource;

        try
        {
            foreach (string[] conn in lines)
            {
                string connectionString = conn[0];

                FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(connectionString);
                fbConn.Open();

                try
                {
                    await getDocuments(fbConn, cancelSource.Token);
                    await getArticles(fbConn, cancelSource.Token);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    fbConn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _cancelSource = null;
        }
    }
}

private async Task getDocuments(FbConnection fbConn, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    DataTable dt = await Task.Run(() => getNewDocuments(fbConn));

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Task.Run(() => sendDocumentsToMySQL((int)dt.Rows[i]["ID"]));
    }
}

private async Task getArticles(FbConnection fbConn, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    DataTable dt = await Task.Run(() => getNewArticles(fbConn));

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Task.Run(() => sendArticlesToMySQL((int)dt.Rows[i]["ID"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I will accept your answer because I know it's correct, but I'm targeting .NET Framework 3.5 and `Async` is for .NET Framework 4.5. Therefore, I implemented `Threads` instead of `Backgroundworkers` and i've solved successfully my problem.