# Handling Background Events on the Main Thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I create a background thread to do some work and, at the very end, I call a method `ThreadDone(threadWorkResult)` which raises an event. Currently, the event handler runs on the same background thread but I would like it to run on the main UI thread (Forms application). I searched online and found something about using attributes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649386.aspx) but would like to know how to do this programatically. Is there any way it can be done outside the body of the handler itself?

I looked into BackgroundWorker but I have to create several threads at once so all of the respective OnWorkerCompleted event handlers become quite messy; more importantly, not all of them require the completed event. Worst case scenario I will use several BackgroundWorkers but is it possible for me to simply call a method (`void aMethod()`) from a background thread and force it to run on the primary UI thread?

Comment: @ Jon : +1 I've updated my answer as per your edit. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use BackgroundWorker thread for the background work and you can then easily handle the UI in the [OnWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted.aspx) event.

Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365887/can-you-link-to-a-good-example-of-using-backgroundworker-without-placing-it-on-a/6365951#6365951) for more information.

**Edit**

You can use a delegate to hand over some tasks to MainUI thread.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(object paramObject);
```

In the background thread call it as below.

```
private void aMethod(object myParam)
{
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
         // We're not in the UI thread, so we need to call BeginInvoke
         BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(aMethod), new object());
         return;
      }

      // Must be on the UI thread if we've got this far.
      // Do UI updates here.      
}
```

See [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/workerthread.aspx) for references.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I may be missing something but doesn't `InvokeRequired` (and `BeginInvoke` for that matter) require a control to be called (i.e. `aControl.InvokeRequired`)? Also, the `MyDelegate` you call out has a signature of void (void) but is being passed `object value` as parameter. Is this possible? And, did you mean to write `UpdateMyUI` instead of `UpdateStatus` in `BeginInvoke`? Like I mentioned previously, I am quite new to C# so I apologize if I just asked a (or several) stupid questions. :)

Comment: @ Jon : Thank you for pointing my errors. I had posted untested code. aControl.InvokeRequired is possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method called `BeginInvoke` on Windows Form controls which will execute code in the GUI thread.