# C# Backgroundworker ConsoleWriteline

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a simple Backgroundworker and want to write my result to the Console and I also want to report the process.

```
 class Program
    {
        private static BackgroundWorker worker;
        static int counter;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                counter++;
                worker.ReportProgress(counter);
            }
        }

        static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
        }

        static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }    
    }
```

But how can I give my String (or more then 1 String) to my ReportProcess Function?

Comment: Change the output in your progress changed. Such as, WriteLine("Current value: {0}",counter)

Comment: i still get no output oO

Comment: Doesnt look like you've assigned the progress changed function to the worker..

Comment: What examples on BackgroundWorker have you researched? There are many out there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365887/can-you-link-to-a-good-example-of-using-backgroundworker-without-placing-it-on-a is just one.

Comment: Its one but not a clearly understanding one :) i dont only want some code i want to understand it ... or to understand how simple give a string to the reportprocess and then write into Console.

Comment: so  take my hint and see where that takes you

Comment: @BugFinder saw it now lol moment

Comment: @BugFinder i dont get it .... i guess i need to go back to School ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning the event handlers to the `BackgroundWorker` events:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork; //here
        worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged; //and here
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're passing counter as the first (int percentProgress) parameter to ReportProgress, which you can access as shown in the example below using e.ProgressPercentage. You can also pass a second (object userState) parameter, which could be a string or any other object, accessed as shown in the example below using e.UserState.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100, "Complete!");
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = e.UserState as String;
}
```

See full example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprogressbar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.UserState as String);
        }

Comment: Also look at Luc Morin's answer below, as well as the full example at the link (if needed).