# C# BackgroundWorker - how should i get rid of DoEvents

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, doevents

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a backgroundworker that is triggered off radio button clicks.  I created a very simple form with 3 radio buttons and a label.  Each of the radio buttons share the same event radioButton_CheckedChanged. If the event completes then I update the label to "Complete".  If you click another radio button before the event completes then update label to Cancelled.   Below is the code i have written in this quick example. Although the application tends to run as expected my concern is the use of Application.DoEvents.  What are my alternatives to this.  For obvious reasons i can't sleep while  IsBusy.  Am I going about this all wrong or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks, poco

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
            if (rb.Checked)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                {
                    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                    while (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                        Application.DoEvents();
                }

                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !worker.CancellationPending; ++i)
                Thread.Sleep(1);

            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
                label1.Text = "Canceled";
            else
                label1.Text = "Complete";
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should move the code that must run when the BackgroundWorker completes into the RunWorkerCompleted hander. In pseudo-code:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        addJobToQueue();   // Don't wait here, just store what needs to be executed.
    } else {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    } 
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled) {
        label1.Text = "Canceled";
    }
    else {
        label1.Text = "Complete";
    }

    // We've finished! See if there is more to do...
    if (thereIsAnotherJobInTheQueue())
    {
         startAnotherBackgroundWorkerTask();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I follow this, I'll go test it out.  I would assume that JobQueue would be on the GUI thread so do i ever run the risk of crossthreading? The only time i would see changing the jobQueue would be in the rb_checkchanged and in the bw_runcompleted which should be back on the main thread right?

Answer (score -1):

`DoEvents` is not supposed to be taken so casually. There are better ways. One of the very nice ones is [described here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123661/net-how-to-wait-for-a-backgroundworker-to-cancel). This answer is probably best for you.

Hence your solution becomes:

```
private AutoResetEvent _resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            _resetEvent.WaitOne(); // will block until _resetEvent.Set() call made
        }

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !worker.CancellationPending; ++i)
        Thread.Sleep(1);

    if (worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    _resetEvent.Set();
}
```

Comment: This results in -> This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently when calling backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()