# VB.NET Application.Exit not closing forms opened using ShowDialog

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, showdialog, .net-cf-3.5

I have a .Net application with multiple forms invoked using `form.ShowDialog()`. When I do `Application.Exit`, the application is not closing all the forms.

When I try to do an explicit `Form.Close` I am getting an error from WinForms as below

> at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar) at System.Windows.Forms.Form._CloseModal() at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close() at

Comment: Could you show us more code? When are you trying to close the application?

Comment: Isn't this `CF` or `WM`?

Comment: I have a thread created which will capture user idle time and if it exceeds a specific value, the application will logoff automatically to inidicate session time out, this will eventually call Application.Exit

Comment: This is indeed CF 3.5 in VB.Net

Comment: If you're calling application.exit in another thread I `think` that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @CharithJ states in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866783/how-to-call-application-exit-on-an-non-ui-thread/6866881#6866881) answer (paraphrased):

Cancel the background worker and send an argument to the `BackgroundWorker` `RunWorkerCompleted` event to identify that time has expired. From that event you can call `Application.Exit()` just fine.

Comment: Maybe append a link to the post you've copied? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866881/1842065

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks for the correction. You're absolutely right. My bad.