# How can i pause/continue backgroundworker?

Tags: c#

I have a button click event for continue:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

And a button click event for pausing:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                button3.Enabled = true;
                soundPlay = false;
                stop_alarm = true;
            }

        }
```

The problem is with the button3 click event the continue code sometimes the background is busy so i can enable false/true the buttons but the backgroundworker is keep working.
I want to pause the DoWork event and to continue.

This is my DoWork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)numericUpDown1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)numericUpDown1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        blinking_label();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                    }
                    cpuView();
                    gpuView();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a `Thread` instead of a `BackgroundWorker`?

With a Thread, in its working subroutine you could put the thread into an infinite sleep inside a try/catch block that catches `ThreadInterruptedException`.  So, as it loops through whatever it's working on, you could look at the value of a boolean flag to know whether or not to sleep, and then call `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`.  When you catch `ThreadInterruptedException` you set the flag to false and continue to execute.

To make the thread resume from your UI, you would set the 'pause' flag to false and call `workerThread.Interrupt()` on your thread (assuming you called it workerThread, that is).

Idea sourced from [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?511402-RESOLVED-2008-Pausing-background-worker-thread)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait until cancellation is done before enable/disable button.

```
private AutoResetEvent _resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                //Wait statement goes here.
                this.Cursor=Cursors.AppStarting;
                _resetEvent.WaitOne(); // will block until _resetEvent.Set() call made

                button3.Enabled = true;
                soundPlay = false;
                stop_alarm = true;
            }

        }
```

[Please see this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123661/how-to-wait-for-a-backgroundworker-to-cancel)

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)numericUpDown1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)numericUpDown1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        blinking_label();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                    }
                    cpuView();
                    gpuView();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }

              _resetEvent.Set(); // signal that worker is done
        }
```