# Close console window after execution without any user input

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, backgroundworker

I have one console application in which I have implement `BackgroundWorker` in loop for dynamically creating thread.If I am not give `console.ReadKey()` than close window immediately without process end. If I give than it waits for user Input for closing. I also try `ManualResetEvent`. In this if I am give

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(_resetEvents)
```

than console window not closed if not give than also same problem window closed before execution completion. In `Thread.Sleep()` if execution taken more time than given time-stamp than also Window close before completion.

Please give proper Solution for this problem.

Comment: This answer covers what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123661/how-to-wait-for-a-backgroundworker-to-cancel

Comment: Nothig do with this!!

Comment: What's was wrong with `ManualResetEvent` approach? Can you post code for this?